# Create a new Azure AD user with the same ID as the on-premise user

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

To follow up on a previous [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519100/create-an-office365-mailbox-from-within-c-sharp-web-api-method/42522507), I’d like to know if this is possible or not.

TLDR; When using `Microsoft Graph` to create a new user, is it possible for that new user to match an on-premise existing AD user?

**The situation:**

We have an on-premise AD that synchronizes with our Azure AD. The default sync process runs every 30 min.

We have an `ASP.NET MVC` application which happens to create a new user inside our on-premise AD. Upon successful creation, I’d like to force synchronization with Azure AD because I have other steps to apply on that particular user such as assigning him a license.

I’m aware of the `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta` cmdlet but I’d have to run that cmdlet from within C# and this might take `X amount` of time to run depending on the amount of users it needs to synchronize.

In addition, I need that command to fully finish before moving ahead with my other steps (apply license for example)

**The question:**

Because of the potential issues with running the `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta`  cmdlet and with the `X amount` of time it may take to run, I was wondering if I could, instead, use `Microsoft Graph` and create a new User.

The problem I *think* I’ll have is that the code already creates an on-premise AD user, then, if I use `Microsoft Graph` to create a user, I’m concern that this will end up creating a different user.

The only reason I’m thinking of using `Graph` to create the user is to not have to run the PowerShell command thus avoiding the `X amount` of time it takes to run.

I guess the question is, is it possible to:

- Create on-premise AD user.
- Obtain some kind of ID from that newly created user and pass that ID
  to the `Microsoft Graph` create user this way, I won’t end up having
  two different users.

At some point in time, when the actual synchronization process occurs, it won’t do anything to that particular user since it will already exist in Azure AD.

I hope I make sense because it’s kind of difficult to verbally explain this

I welcome any different approaches or ideas.

Sincerely

Comment: Instead of using the **Password Sync** for SSO, do you consider using **Federation with AD FS** which users are able to sign in to Microsoft cloud services, such as Office 365, using the same password they use in their on-premises network and the users are redirected to their on-premises AD FS instance to sign in and authentication occurs on-premises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible (although I've not tried it).  The important thing here is to ensure that linkage, you set the `onPremisesImmutableId` property as part of creation.  Please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user. I don't think we have any examples of creating a user with this property set, but it should be straightforward, and for federated users is actually required. By default the onPremisesImmutableId is the ADObjectId for the on-premises AD user, unless you've configured ADConnect to use something else.

NOTE: you should be able to do the same thing using Azure AD PowerShell - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azuread/v2/new-azureaduser (although here the property is called immutableId).

Hope this helps,

Comment: So if I understand correctly, after programmatically creating the on-premise AD user, I should retrieve the ADObjectId newly created. Then use Graph to POST and create a new user. Within that POST, set the onPremisesImmutableId property’s value to the ADObjectId and voila!

For the record, later that day when AD Connect kicks in and does its synchronization thing, it will not need to synchronize that particular ADObjectId (or simply ignore it) since that user will be existing on both on-premise AD and Azure AD right?

Comment: Correct.  I think when you set the onPremisesImmutableId property, you may need to based64 encode it.  I'll check and get back to you - or you can try an experiment ;)